# Steer clear from vs steer clear of

Tags: grammar

Question, can I use the preposition **from** instead of **of** if I'm talking about actions instead of people with that expression? For example:

> Guy #1: I'm not a big fan of women with stretch marks and cellulite.
>
> Guy #2: You might as well **steer clear from/of** dating women altogether then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is *steer clear **of***.

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=steer%20clear%20of%2C%20steer%20clear%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csteer%20clear%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csteer%20clear%20from%3B%2Cc0) shows that "steer clear from" is never or rarely used, and I would write any examples off as mistakes.

If you do hear people say it, they may be mixing it up with similar expressions that use "from", such as:

- stay away *from* drugs
- keep clean *from* drugs

These mean pretty much the same thing as "steer clear *of* drugs".

The word "clear" has many uses and definitions, but the [relevant definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/clear) here is:

> *Not touching; away from*.
>
> "the lorry was wedged in the ditch, one wheel clear of the ground"

Examples in other dictionaries all use "clear *of*" for this definition also.

Comment: [Cambridge Online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steer-clear-of-sb-sth) also has a dedicated listing for the idiomatic use of "steer clear of".